# Unknown class CustomViewController in Interface Builder file using a storyboard from a library

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker, storyboard, static-libraries

I've read many other questions about this but didn't find a solution right now and my issue is perhaps a little more specific than what I could see elsewhere.

So currently I build a static library including some other frameworks, a bundle with graphic resources + storyboard and subclasses of UIViewController assigned in "Class" field of my storyboard's view controller.

When I use my lib in a test project, it seems I can load the view controller from storyboard but I crashes with "unrecognized selector sent to instance" once I press any control in the view.
Also Xcode reports : "Unknown class CustomViewController in Interface Builder file." before.

Here is the code I'm using to load it:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"careersbundle" withExtension:@"bundle"]];

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

self.sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:bundle];
self.vc = [self.sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Player"];

[self.window setRootViewController:self.vc];
//...
```

As I understand, I don't need to reference any .h file in includes as my project only needs to load the ViewController and it should then work on his own with IBAction.

I see that setting project's "Other Linker Flag" to -ObjC should help but dosen't solve my issue. I set this flag in my library project (not the test project) but I'm not sure I'm doing it right like this ?

I also see developers using "[CustomViewController class]" to force linker to keep reference to class but they use it in main.c and I didn't have a main.c in my library project...

I'm lost with this, can someone point me to settings I have to do in the library project and then in my test project to make it works.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally implemented the complete interface in code using nib2objc tool to convert my storyboards views's properties in code.